# Change http requests to https using .htaccess file in Zend framework 2.0

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an application written in Zend Framework 2.0. The ssl certificate has been configured in the production site. HTTPS requests made by the user is fine. I want to change all the HTTP requests made by the users to HTTPS.

I used the code written below in my .htaccess file inside public folder (in IIS server).

```
 RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

But, the problem is Let I type the URL http://carecenter.helptocare.com. It's changing to https://carecenter.helptocare.com/carecenter/public/index.php.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with ZF2, but rather the Apache mod-rewrite module. Changed tags and tidied your question a bit.

Comment: I don't know if you can edit vhosts, but if you can you might want to read http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html#redirect once you have it working.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply google it. Here's a quick example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Found [here](http://www.sslshopper.com/apache-redirect-http-to-https.html)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have apache server, not IIS, this will not work for IIS. The order of rules are important here:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```